# Angular directive without scope defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I would like to know what it mean when directive definition have no *scope:*, and also what would be equivalent if I where to add *scope:*.

Like this example:

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
  };
});
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.  Clearly laid out in the documentation, and much too much information to cut and paste into an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: It means that it that the directive inherits the scope of the controller and doesn't have its own 'isolate scope'.

Not having an isolate scope means more coupling with the controller and less reusability (as it depends on the controller's scope).

Comment: What would be equivalent "scope:"? "scope: true" ?

Comment: yes, if you want an isolated scope in the directive.

Comment: did the answer help you?

Comment: No. I do not want to change any behaviour. I ask what is equivalent "scope:" notation to having no "scope:". Is there equivalent?

Comment: To not have an isolate scope, dont have a scope property in your directive.